# Are these two statements on predicates equivalent?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$\forall x [P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)] \Rightarrow [\forall x P(x) \rightarrow \forall x Q(x)]$

$\forall x [P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)] \Rightarrow [\forall y P(y) \rightarrow \forall z Q(z)]$

How do you prove them if it's the case?

I mean, we don't know the domain of x, y or z.

For instance if  the LHS is true for x, but the RHS is false for y and z, then we'd have a contradiction, right?

Do we have to do a proof by case, where if the LHS is false, the RHS is false or true, and if the LHS is true, the RHS must be true?

I don't know how to prove the RHS is true if the LHS is true, because the variables aren't the same.

Comment: The names of quantified variables are irrelevant.  The formula $\forall{x}\phi(x)$ is always equivalent to $\forall{y}\phi(y)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s understood that the domains of the quantifiers are all the same.

Let’s take an informal look.

- $\forall x[P(x)\to Q(x)]$ says that if you pick an $x$ from the relevant domain, and it happens to have property $P$, then it will also have property $Q$.
- $\forall xP(x)\to\forall xQ(x)$ says that if every element of the domain has property $P$, then every element of the domain has property $Q$. There’s no real connection between the $x$ in $\forall xP(x)$ and the $x$ in $\forall xQ(x)$: the scope of the first quantifier extends only over $P(x)$.
- $\forall yP(y)\to\forall zQ(z)$ also says that if every element of the domain has property $P$, then every element of the domain has property $Q$. This version just makes explicit, by using different variables, the fact that the scope of the first quantifier extends only over $P(y)$; it doesn’t reach the righthand side of the implication.

Informally, then, we can see that

$$\forall x [P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)] \Rightarrow [\forall x P(x) \rightarrow \forall x Q(x)]\tag{1}$$

and

$$\forall x [P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)] \Rightarrow [\forall y P(y) \rightarrow \forall z Q(z)]\tag{2}$$

say the same thing. The point of the exercise is that if a variable is *bound*, meaning that it’s governed by (technically, *within the scope of*) some quantifier, it is **not** the same as any other bound variable, even if they share the same name. Statement $(1)$ actually contains three different variables that are all called $x$; in statement $(2)$ they are given different names.

By the way, $(1)$ (and therefore $(2)$) is true, though that apparently isn’t part of the exercise.

**Added:** A similar phenomenon from another part of mathematics may be helpful. Suppose that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous, real-valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$, and that $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Consider the following (true) statements:

$$\begin{align*}
&\int_0^1f(x)~dx\le\int_0^1g(x)~dx\tag{3}\\
&\int_0^1f(x)~dx\le\int_0^1g(y)~dy\tag{4}
\end{align*}$$

$(3)$ and $(4)$ are exactly equivalent, even though $(3)$ uses the same variable on both sides of the inequality, and $(4)$ uses different variables. These definite integrals are just numbers, and the value of that number is independent of the name of the variable of integration. The $x$ in the lefthand integral in $(3)$ isn’t actually the same as the $x$ in the righthand integral: each in a sense ‘exists’ only within its own integral. The bound variables in your statements are similarly tied to the scopes of their respective quantifiers and in a sense ‘exist’ only within those scopes.